# Why print in Python doesn't pause when using sleep in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Causes my computer to hang for 5 seconds, and then print out 0-9, as opposed to printing a digit every half second.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know much python, but do you need to print a newline character to have the output printed to the console?

Comment: no,  As I said, this does print the digits, just without a delay in between them.

Comment: it working fine on my computer

Comment: Working fine on mine too. Do you maybe have an indentation issue? For the record I'm using python3.4

Comment: No. I think this must be a problem with the Python interpreter in the program I am using.  It was not run purely in Python but an application that uses Python for scripting. That must be the issue.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: @Startec I am able to reproduce the problem and I have explained the solution in my answer, please check. Others, don't use the interactive shell, which is line-buffered, try writing the code in a file and execute it with the interpreter.

Comment: @Startec that is the reason, python behaves differently when it recognizes that the `stdout` is connected to a terminal, vs it is connected to a pipe, or a file. Your embedded interpreter does the latter.

Comment: One can reproduce the behaviours on Unix by doing `python prog.py|cat`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), by default, prints to `sys.stdout` and that buffers the output to be printed, internally.

> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the `flush` keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.
>
> Changed in version 3.3: Added the `flush` keyword argument.

Quoting [`sys.stdout`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout),

> When interactive, standard streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files.

So, in your case, you need to explicitly flush, like this

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

---

Okay, there is a lot of confusion around this buffering. Let me explain as much as possible.

First of all, if you are trying this program in a terminal, they do **line buffering** (which basically means, whenever you encounter a newline character, send the buffered data to `stdout`), by default. So, you can reproduce this problem in Python 2.7, like this

```
>>> import time
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print i,
...     time.sleep(.5)
...
```

And in Python 3.x,

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(i, end='')
...     time.sleep(.5)
```

We pass `end=''` because, the default `end` value is `\n`, as per the [`print`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print),

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Since the default `end` breaks the line buffering, the data will be sent to `stdout` immediately.

Another way to reproduce this problem is to store the actual program given by OP in a file and execute with Python 3.x interpreter, you will see that the `stdout` internally buffers the data and waits till the program finishes to print.

Comment: @vks No it is not. I am able to reproduce the problem. Don't use the interactive shell, which is line-buffered, try writing the code in a file and execute it with the interpreter.

Comment: @vks Because the interactive shell is line buffered, so you couldn't see the difference. It prints immediately.

Comment: @vks That is exactly the point. The code in loop runs 10 times, and all the data written to `stdout` are buffered. So nothing gets printed for 5 seconds (10 * 0.5 seconds) and finally when the program exits, `stdout` is flushed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71744/discussion-between-thefourtheye-and-vks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(10):
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(i))
        time.sleep(.5)
```

here `'/r'` is carriage return, it brings the cursor first place again.