# Slow print waiting too long before printing

Tags: python

The code below should (I believe) print a character, wait for 0.4 seconds then print next character, but it waits for 1.6 seconds and then prints the hole string.

Here is some code I tried

```py
import time

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='')
        time.sleep(.4)

print_slow("junk")
```

What I expect: `j ... u ... n ... k`
What I get: `......... junk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't define the flush of the print stdout. By not including the flush=True in the print command, it will just store all the characters in the buffer until the function call resolves, and it all prints in a single instance.

```
import time

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(.4)

print_slow("junk")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush `stdout` on every write. Otherwise your print gets buffered and written at once when program ends:

```
import sys
import time

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.4)

print_slow("junk")
```

Edit:

You can run your script by invoking python with `-u` flag: `python3 -u <scriptname.py>`

> -u     : force the binary I/O layers of stdout and stderr to be unbuffered;
>            stdin is always buffered; text I/O layer will be line-buffered;
>            also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x

Comment: still not working?

Comment: To expand upon this answer. 
When you execute a print() statement, the characters you're trying to print get buffered before being outputted on stdout. On some systems (like mine, fedora 30) your code works exactly as expected, the buffer is flushed after each character write. On others, the same wont happen.

Comment: @PhysicalExperience try to run your script with `-u` flag: `python3 -u <yourscriptname.py>`

Comment: nothing, this problem only occurs when I print with ```end=''```

Comment: @PhysicalExperience do you run the script from console or from IDE?

Comment: i run it from atom. Now I tried it from cmd and it worked! Can I get it working in Atom too? It is much easier with shortcuts.

Comment: @PhysicalExperience I don't have experience with atom but try to find somewhere in Options how your script is being run. Either add flag `-u` to python executable or check option that you want unbuffered output.

Comment: thanks! my package had some configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

This question is potentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736175/why-print-in-python-doesnt-pause-when-using-sleep-in-a-loop).

Basically, print is buffering `stdout`. You need to flush the output on each iteration:

```py
print(letter, end='', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time, sys

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.4)

print_slow("junk")
```

just need to force the terminal to show the output