# Why is my sleep not sleeping when i say but before I say in python

Tags: python, sleep

I gave the code below and it's in python

```
from time import *
# I dont need to use time every time 
print("hi" ,end="")
sleep(3)
print("." ,end="")
sleep(3)
print("." ,end="")
sleep(3)
print("." )
```

I got hi... but it took 9-10 seconds before it printing any thing and din't give any gap in middle

Comment: Check `flush` argument of [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Comment: This works when I am not using end="" , but i need it to be in the same line

Comment: think it works i am very new to python so I know only a very few things but I am learning it I bit hard as I am 13 years thanks for the help

Comment: wait I can't do it know as this is not allowing know, it asks me to wait !!

Comment: what does flush do when we add it can you explain the functionality

Comment: @saiprabhav See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736175/why-print-in-python-doesnt-pause-when-using-sleep-in-a-loop

Comment: hear can anyone help me learn python and do we have the access to add anyone as friends in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `flush` parameter as `True` makes your `print()` statements print in time.

```
from time import sleep

print("hi", end="", flush=True)
sleep(3)

for i in range(3):
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: "*Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword argument, or when used to indicate a default value for an unannotated function parameter*" © [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations).

Comment: *"Use 4 spaces per indentation level"* © [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, my code was auto-formatted when I copy pasted in an online python ide.