# Hey, I've written a small python program for printing a loading bar but it is not working, Could you guys please look into it

Tags: python

So I've written down this very small code of a loading bar, but when I hit run, it's just waiting for sometime like about 10 secs and then it prints out the entire 20 "-" all at once without waiting for 2 secs as it is expected to do, am I doing wrong. Why is it printing 20 "-" all at once without printing it one by one and waiting for 2 secs in between. Please help.

----Raw code----

```
import time

for i in range(20):
  print ("-", end = "")
  time.sleep(2)
```

output:

```
-------------------
```

Comment: works with me a single - added every 2 secs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why print in Python doesn't pause when using sleep in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736175/why-print-in-python-doesnt-pause-when-using-sleep-in-a-loop)

Comment: so solution is use print("-", end = "", flush=True)

Comment: right was working in ide not on console

Comment: @RandomDavis hey thanks dude. Now it's working fine !!!!!

Comment: @pippo1980 thanks buddy, now it's working perfectly fine !!!