# How `end` parameter for `print()' works in python when I use `time.sleep()`?

Tags: python, buffer

I wanted to print `1 2 3 4 5` with 2 seconds of sleep gaps by using `end` parameter for `print()`.

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i)

1
2
3
4
5
```

This code prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 line by line with 2 seconds of sleep gaps.

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i, end=" ")

1 2 3 4 5  # It is printed at once after 10 seconds
```

However, when I use the `end` parameter for `print()`, it prints 1 2 3 4 5 at once after 10 seconds of sleep.

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i, end=" ", flush=True)

1 2 3 4 5  # Each number is printed with 2 seconds of sleep as I expected.
```

Finally, I found a way to print 1 2 3 4 5 with 2 seconds of sleep gap each, by setting `flush=True`.

Can anyone help me to understand how the `end` causes this issue?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: [Why print in Python doesn't pause when using sleep in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736175/why-print-in-python-doesnt-pause-when-using-sleep-in-a-loop)