Can't execute a remote Python script with sleep(.) from SSH
I am trying to execute a Python script on a remote server via SSH. The script is supposed to run a certain function every few seconds. A minimal working snippet is as follows:
# test.py (this is on the remote server in $HOME)
import sys
import time

def test(num_samples):
    # First start with a monitoring period of 50 seconds.
    monitoring_period = 5
    a = 0
    
    while a < num_samples:
        print(a, num_samples)
        time.sleep(monitoring_period)        
        a += 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Start")
    test(int(sys.argv[1]))

When I run the above script directly on the remote server, it executes successfully:
node0:~$ python test.py 500
Start
0 500

However, when I try to run the same script via SSH - it just stalls (and note that even the first print statement "Start" is also not executed:
❯ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<remote-server> "pushd \$HOME; python test.py 500"
~ ~
// It stalls here

More interestingly, if I remove the time.sleep(.) statement from the above script, it executes just fine:
❯ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<remote-server> "pushd \$HOME; python test.py 500"
~ ~
Start
0 500


What exactly is going on? Does the sleep(.) statement cause this issue?
If so, is the Python interpreter somehow checking for it before even executing the first statement in the script (the print("Start") statement)?


Add flush=True to the print() calls.

When there is a long pause done in command passed to execute over SSH, the SSH might think is in idle state and stop forwarding the output. So the output was buffered but not flushed (doesn't show up). The easiest way will be to add "-u" paramater to the python command. It stands for "unbuffered output":
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<remote-server> "pushd \$HOME; python -u test.py 500"

In such case you won't need to modify the script by forcing prints to flush.

This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736175/why-print-in-python-doesnt-pause-when-using-sleep-in-a-loop
